# Extract value of each column and store in a list/dictionary for each index value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 5 columns. I want to look through 3 of them and store in dict or list (whichever is more efficient) the values of each of the 5 columns

Example:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20 | 9 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 55 | 14 | 5 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 9 | 7 | 7 |

I would like to create three lists as such

```
index_1 = [10,20,4]
index_2 = [4,55,2]
index_3 = [3,3,7]
```

I have no idea how to go forward after looping through the columns

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'E']
for col in cols:
    df[col]
```

Comment: @It_is_Chris this is combining all values under a column for each key (column). I want the opposite where each key refers to the index and the values are to be the index respective column values

Comment: Sorry, try numpy: `np.transpose(df.T.loc[cols].values)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
index_1, index_2, index_3 = [list(row) for row in df[["A", "B", "E"]].values]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `locals()` to create 3 python variables:

```py
cols = ['A', 'B', 'E']

for idx, col in enumerate(cols, 1):
    locals()[f"index_{idx}"] = df[col].tolist()
```

```
>>> index_1
[10, 4, 3]

>>> index_2
[20, 55, 3

>>> index_3
[4, 2, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try

```
d = df[['A','B','E']].T.to_dict('list')
Out[227]: {1: [10, 20, 4], 2: [4, 55, 2], 3: [3, 3, 7]}
d[1]
Out[231]: [10, 20, 4]
```